# how to use join query in yii2.0

Tags: php, yii2

I am using this code to find data by id form my database table user.

```
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
```

Here what i want is to use join to get the state name based on the state_id, fetching from the current query.

I used the following code but getting errors:

```
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id)->joinWith('state')->All(),
    ]);
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the `state` relation in the `User` model file.

If you need the State's name based on `state_id` that exists in the User's table then,

write -

```
return $this->render('view', [
    'model' => $this->findModel($id),
]);
```

then in view file, get the state's name using the `state` relation like -

```
$model->state->name;         //name is the column from the `state` table
```

and that should do it.